# Difference between double value in Oracle and Java (IEEE 754)

Tags: java, oracle, floating-point, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

BINARY_DOUBLE in Oracle and Double in Java use IEEE 754 standard.

But there is the difference in their accuracy.

For example value:

> 456.67d

Oracle:

```
declare
  a BINARY_DOUBLE := 456.67d;
begin
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_Line(TO_CHAR(a,'9.99999999999999999999EEEE'));
end;
```

> Result: 4.56670000000000020000E+02

Java:

```
Double d = 456.67d;
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000000000000000000000E000");
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

> Result: 4.566700000000000000000E002

The value in Java is not as accurate as in Oracle.

Online converters said that the most accurate representation for 456.67d is:

> 4.56670000000000015916157281026E2

So why in Java accuracy is not the same like in Oracle?
And how I can get in Java more accurate value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
Double d = 456.67d;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( d );
bd.setScale( 50 );
System.out.println( bd );
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000000000000000000000E000");
System.out.println( formatter.format( bd ) );
```

Output:

```
456.67000000000001591615728102624416351318359375
4.566700000000000159162E002
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are accurate. They just use a different strategy for printing.

Here are the exact values printed via Squeak Smalltalk (but the language doesn't matter, that's same representation and same arithmetic):

```
d := 456.67.
{
    d predecessor asFraction printShowingMaxDecimalPlaces: 50.
    d asFraction printShowingMaxDecimalPlaces: 50.
    d successor asFraction printShowingMaxDecimalPlaces: 50}.
```

->

```
#(
    '456.6699999999999590727384202182292938232421875'
    '456.67000000000001591615728102624416351318359375'
    '456.670000000000072759576141834259033203125'
)
```

So any decimal representation between `(d predecessor asFraction + d asFraction) / 2 printShowingMaxDecimalPlaces: 50.` and `(d successor asFraction + d asFraction) / 2 printShowingMaxDecimalPlaces: 50.` is going to be rounded to the same floating point value (bounds excluded, because the exact tie is rounded to nearest even, and this float has odd significand...)

So the bounds are:

```
#(
    '456.669999999999987494447850622236728668212890625'
    '456.670000000000044337866711430251598358154296875'
)
```

Oracle just use 17 digits and doesn't bother with further digits because 17 is known to be enough to distinguish any two double precision floating point values.

Java is a bit more clever: it use just enough digits to distinguish from next representable floating point values. So putting 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 at position 17, or even 4.5666999999999999e2 does not matter, it's still the same floating point value.